# Google Places API returning random results for various rankby and radar search combinations

Tags: google-maps, google-places-api

For rankby search I hit the following URL, today morning around 11:00AM Indian time:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=41.703625,-71.493149&rankby=distance&type=cafe&key=&name=BrewedAwakenings

I got 5 Brewed Awakenings Cafes

Now  whenever I hit the exact same URL I get only 4 Brewed Awakenings Cafes

---

In another problem with rankby search for following URL:

https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=42.351463,-71.050446&rankby=distance&type=cafe&key=

I get a Starbucks cafe at the address:
303 Congress Street, Boston

Now when I hit the same URL with an additional parameter &name=Starbucks this cafe goes missing from the response
Following URL
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=42.351463,-71.050446&rankby=distance&type=cafe&key=&name=Starbucks

(Starbucks cafe, at 303 Congress Street, Boston, is missing)

---

In radar search also, using following URL, we get varied results for this Boston cafe:
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/radarsearch/json?location=42.351463,-71.050446&radius=32186.90&type=cafe&sensor=true&key=&name=%22Starbucks%22

Sometimes following place id cafe comes and sometimes it doesn't
Place Id: ChIJcZkjBYBw44kR1iTeLn1efm0

It varies even when we pass the name with or without double quotes.

---

Also, the google doc for places API says we can pass "name" parameter with pipe separated values
But that gives varied results depending on the sequence of the names and also based on whether we give spaces in long names or not

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be reporting 4 different issues in Places API Nearby and Radar search. The correct way to do this would be to [file bugs](http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-api-issues/issues/entry?template=Places%20API%20-%20Bug) separately for each of these issues.

Comment: All are actually quite connected.
Anyway, had raised a combined issue on google bug tracker as well. They replied saying that is how it is expected to work. Results might change a bit when things change at their backend.